# Javascript passing a picture to a function as a parameter

Tags: javascript, html

Hey guys so I'm trying to pass a picture of type .png as a parameter to a function. So everytime i call the function with a picture parameter the picture will display.
Here is my function

```
    function DisplayImages(picture1){
     document.write("<div class='slideshow'>",
      "<ul>",
        "<li>",
         "<img src=",picture1,"/>",          
          "<div>",
             "<a href=", picture1 "title='Click to see full image' target='_blank'>",
                "<img src=", picture1 " alt='Item 1' />",
            "</a>",
            "<p>'This is Item 1' </p>",
        "</div>",
        "</ul>",
       "</div>");
    }
```

and i calling it like this

```
    <script> DisplayImages('images/upcomingitem1.png'); </script>
```

but its not showing anything, any help how to fix this?

Comment: If that's really exactly what your code looks like, the answer will be found in your browser's error console.

Comment: Missing comma ? `"<img src=", picture1 " alt='Item 1' />",`

Comment: A couple commas actually. Concatenation isn't necessary since `document.write` is variadic.

Comment: @TravisJ though I haven't found documentation that affirms it, the `document.write()` function appears to join its arguments into a single string, so commas are OK.

Comment: @Pointy - Oh, it uses `.join` behind the scenes for multiple arguments, or something equivalent?

Comment: i replaced them with + , but it still the same,nothing

Comment: @TravisJ yes apparently.

Comment: @IsraelRodriguez in the `<a>` tag you're missing a space before the "title" attribute - that'll cause the href to be incorrect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you add the two missing commas, the missing space after the second `src`, and the missing `</li>`, it "works" :

```
function DisplayImages(picture1){
     document.write("<div class='slideshow'>",
      "<ul>",
        "<li>",
         "<img src=\"", picture1,"\">",          
          "<div>",
             "<a href=\"", picture1, "\" title='Click to see full image' target='_blank'>",
                "<img src=\"", picture1, "\" alt='Item 1' />",
            "</a>",
            "<p>'This is Item 1' </p>",
        "</div></li>",
        "</ul>",
       "</div>");
}
```

I also added a few (escaped) quotes, so it works with any URL.

[DEMONSTRATION](http://jsfiddle.net/dJDtF/)

But I'm doubtful about the solution. The whole tree seems heavy.

Comment: thanks man, i have to go to work, so ill accept your answer as soon as i come back

Comment: I don't think the `</li>` should be necessary. Also, though I have no idea what the point is, the `<a>` tag's "href" will be messed up without a space before "title".

Comment: I don't know if there are any valid URL characters that are not valid *unquoted attribute value* characters, but to be safe, it may be good to wrap the href in quotes. ...EDIT: Looks like you just did. :) +1

Answer (score 0):

Properly format your string to write, `+` concatenates, not `,`

```
 function DisplayImages(picture1){
 document.write("<div class='slideshow'>"+
  "<ul>"+
    "<li>"+
     "<img src="+picture1+"/>"+          
      "<div>"+
         "<a href="+ picture1 +"title='Click to see full image' target='_blank'>"+
            "<img src="+ picture1 +" alt='Item 1' />"+
        "</a>"+
        "<p>This is Item 1 </p>"+
    "</div>"+
    "</ul>"+
   "</div>");
 }
```

Comment: Commas are correct. There were just some missing.

Comment: Interesting, I did not know that it would accept arguments and then format them from commas.

Comment: That's just like `console.log` : it's a variadic function.